# Why don't two QNX virtual machines on Windows 7 connect through QNet?

Tags: vmware, qnx, qnx-neutrino

Details: two identical QNX 6.5.0 installed on VMware Player under Windows 7 on the different computers. In VMware settings network connection is bridged.

Each QNX can ping another. For enabling QNet I run this:

```
mount -T io-pkt /lib/dll/lsm-qnet.so
```

but QNet doesn't work. On both machines in `/net` directory appears a folder for itself. But instead a folder for another QNX machine appears a damaged file with no size, owner, permissions or smth else. In file information is written "Host is down" or sometimes "No route to host".

P.S. I already turned off any antiviruses and all that.

Comment: On the same computer it works fine. Problem only when VMs running on different computers.

Comment: Are you using IP addresses or host names? If host names, you need DNS. Also try with Window firewalls disabled. http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/sys_arch/qnet.html

Comment: I'm using IP addresses. And all firewalls already disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, by default, qnet does not route over IP, but is its own packet type over Ethernet.

VMWare probably knows nothing about Qnet packet types, and the networking drivers probably don't either.

However, you can modify the QNX network stacks to route Qnet over IP packets, and this will let Qnet pass through IP routers.  See the QNX documentation for instructions on configuring the neutrino TCP/IP to do this.